# Matlab equivalent to Mathematica's Table or Array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm very new to Matlab. I want to specify an M by N matrix by a M_{ij} = f(i,j). In Mathematica I would write `Table[f[i,j], {i,1,m}, {j,1,n}]` or even more simply `Array[f,{m,n}]`. What is the simplest way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: Have a look at ndgrid/meshgrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mathematica syntax but my understanding of

> M_{ij} = f(i,j)

would be

```
%// I'm making up a function f(x,y), this could be anonymous as in my example or a function in an .m file
f = @(x,y) sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);  %// note it's important that this function works on matrices (i.e. is vectorized) hence the use of .^ instead of ^

%// make i and j indexing data. Remember Matlab is numerical in nature, I suggest you inspect the contents of X and Y to get a feel for how to work in Matlab...
m = 2;
n = 3;
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:m, 1:n);
```

now it's just:

```
M = f(X,Y)
```

results in

```
M = 
    1.4142    2.2361    3.1623
    2.2361    2.2824    3.6056
```

i.e.

```
 M = [f(1,1), f(1,2), f(1,3);
      f(2,1), f(2,2), f(2,3)]
```